# Source of electrons in Crooks tube experiment (Inside the Discharge tube)

Tags: electricity, photoelectric-effect, subatomic

In the experiment, gases are put at low pressure inside the discharge tube. Now the issue that arises is a very simple one.

[This is the animation for the experiment](http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/olcweb/cgi/pluginpop.cgi?it=swf::100%25::100%25::/sites/dl/free/0072512644/117354/01_Cathode_Ray_Tube.swf::Cathode%20Ray%20Tube). Its pretty obvious that the electrons are originating from the Cathode. This basically means that the metal is 'releasing' its electrons so as to complete the circuit. However my chemistry teacher told me that the gases inside the tube are ionized, thus providing the necessary electrons to complete the circuit.

However, shouldn't the metal/cathode/wire release its electrons as well to complete the circuit? I mean if it doesn't, then how is the kinetic energy of the electrons in the circuit transferred to the electrons released from the ionized gases, and why is cathode the source in that case.

I have studied about thermionic emission by heating metals, that asserts a threshold for the metal. However if the battery drives the electrons then shouldn't they be released as well?

My basic question to you is, where do the electrons come from and how their energy is transferred throughout the circuit.

Comment: The electrons jump from the cathode into the plasma, travel through the plasma, and are accelerated. Most strike the anode and complete the circuit, but some go through the hole and hit the fluorescent screen (after which they presumably get sucked into the anode, completing the circuit).

Comment: Sorry, but you've got your experiments mixed up. The link you provide describes a cathode ray tube (CRT), not a discharge tube. A CRT requires a very high vacuum, and any light is produced by electrons hitting the phosphor screen. A discharge tube has a weak vacuum, and light is produced by ionizing the gas in the tube.